# Send Datadog tags in exometer

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, statsd, datadog

I am using [exometer](https://github.com/Feuerlabs/exometer) and the [exometer_report_statsd](https://github.com/Feuerlabs/exometer/blob/master/src/exometer_report_statsd.erl) reporter to report Phoenix endpoints response times to Datadog via dogstatsd.

From a Plug, I am calling `:exometer.update/2` to send the response time to Datadog.

E.g:

`:exometer.update [:app_name, :webapp, :resp_time], 25`

Now, I want to have only one metric `app_name.webapp.resp_time` instead of one metric per endpoint and version so I thought of using tags.

The question is, where should I include the tags?

Comment: Looking at the way the dogstastd datagram is formatted [here](https://github.com/Feuerlabs/exometer/blob/master/src/exometer_report_statsd.erl#L73), I don't _think_ that tags are supported by this exometer library, but maybe somehow they're passed in as an "extra"? I think your best bet is probably to start an issue directly on the repo to ask the authors of the library to add that support. It should be pretty easy--the datagram just needs to have an extra optional string appended to it like: `|#tag1,tag2,etc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering just in case someone will spot this question via Google.

You cannot. StatsD protocol do not define tags or comments at all, so there is no possibility for that. You need to use different library like [Statix](https://github.com/lexmag/statix) for that.